# Preventing Row Elimination depending on Number of Rows

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements

I have a Spreadsheet that needs to maintain at least 17 rows of content. Column B lists the number of the row. I used the macro recorder to develop some code :

```
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Find(What:="1", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
```

What I'm hoping to do is: If the number of cells in the selected range is less than 18 then exit sub, else (run code).

Comment: Are the users free to select any cells?

Comment: The code I wrote sets the selected range equal to the number of rows of content in the form. Users are free to select any cells but it won't affect the selection that is active at the end of the code above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the trick

```
Columns("B:B").Select
 Selection.Find(What:="1", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues,  LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Dim c As Range
Set c = Selection
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(c) < 18 Then
msg77 = MsgBox("Cannot Delete the Row since there are fewer than 18 Rows", vbOKOnly, "Sorry, I Cannot Serve your Request")
Exit Sub
Else
Selection.Copy
End If
```

Comment: In this case, no need to dim c As range and set it as Selection.

Comment: So take out `Dim c As Range, Set c = Selection` and replace `If WorksheetFunction.CountA(c) < 18 Then` as `If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Selection) < 18 Then` Your code will be faster by a very little margin.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but with the limited knowledge, this is the best I can come up with:

```
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Selection
    If c.Value < 18 Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        'Run Code (Your code here)
    End If
Next c
```

Cheers,
kpark

Comment: c.Value evaluates as 1 in this instance. I need maybe cellcount or something ... I'll look through object browser see if I can find something.

Comment: @RichardPullman I am not sure what you mean by c.Value evaluating to 1 in your instance. Perhaps, `Selection.Find()` is not working properly? and maybe the lines after `Find()` is not working..

Comment: It works it's just that c.value seems to count the number of ranges selected since c is a range variable?  This works... 
   
    `If WorksheetFunction.CountA(c) < 18 Then `

Comment: OHHHHH I read the question wrong :P I thought you were asking for values. haha. cheers.